# Angular2-text-mask

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

Como aplicar uma máscara de telefone aonde se adapte a um telefone fixo e celular, usando o `Angular2-text-mask`?

Li a documentação e vi que da pra fazer com função, porem como estou utilizando `formGroup`, não sei como pegar o valor do meu campo...

```html
    // Mascaras
    cpfMask = [/\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '.', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '.', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/];
    cepMask = [/\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/ , /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/];
   
    
    constructor(fb: FormBuilder, public router: Router, private vwServicePagination: VwServicePagination){
        //Grupo de formulario - Validações
        this.myForm = fb.group({
            nome: new FormControl('', [ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), this.validaNome ]),
            email: new FormControl('', [ Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.validaEmail) ]),
            cpf: new FormControl('', [ Validators.required, this.validaCpf ]),
            telefone: new FormControl('', [ Validators.required ]),
            cep: new FormControl('', [ Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.validaCep) ])
        });
    }
```

***Tentativa de mascara...***

```html
 
    // Mascaras
    cpfMask = [/\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '.', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '.', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/];
    cepMask = [/\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/ , /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/];
    telefoneMask = function(){
        if(this.myForm.controls.telefone.value.length === 9){
            [/\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/ , /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/];
        }else{
            [/\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/ , '-', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/];
        }
    }

    constructor(fb: FormBuilder, public router: Router, private vwServicePagination: VwServicePagination){
        //Grupo de formulario - Validações
        this.myForm = fb.group({
            nome: new FormControl('', [ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), this.validaNome ]),
            email: new FormControl('', [ Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.validaEmail) ]),
            cpf: new FormControl('', [ Validators.required, this.validaCpf ]),
            telefone: new FormControl('', [ Validators.required ]),
            cep: new FormControl('', [ Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.validaCep) ])
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema resolvido! Adicionei um "#telefone" no input do meu HTML, e coloquei a mascara da seguinte forma:

```html
 telefoneMask = function(telefone: any) {
        if(telefone.length == 10){
            return [/\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/ , /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/];
        }else{
            return [/\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/];
        }
    }
```

passando o "#telefone", na função da mascara, consigo pegar o valor dentro do campo e realizar a condição de formação da mascara.

Answer (score 1):

//OnInit

```
this.myForm.controls['telefone'].valueChanges.subscribe(sualogicaaqui)
```

Comment: Tentei usar dessa maneira porem não deu certo!! inseri o código da minha tentativa na pergunta, pois aqui nos comentários tem limite de caracteres...

Comment: Eita o value changes e um observable que vc poe no onInit e acho que não e so mudar o valor da mascara! Vc tem que remover o validator e adicionar o certo.

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-implement-conditional-validation-in-angular-2-model-driven-forms

Comment: Dessa forma também não rolou! :/
Tenho que achar um jeito de usar o 'Angular2-text-mask'